# Script is loading outside div

Tags: javascript, html, css, flask

Hoping for some help please. I have a flask based site and a particular page i'm trying to load a script within a div. Since i'm extending my "base" template, it should follow my design and render script contents with alignment which is already in place. For some reason it loads outside of the page. It does come with it's own CSS so I wonder if it overrides bootstrap defaults?

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='/css/next.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='/css/styles_main_page.css')}}">
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="w-100 p-3">
        <div class="h-100 d-inline-block">
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='/js/next.js')}}" defer></script>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='/js/topology.js')}}" defer></script>
            <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='/js/next_app.js')}}" defer></script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Just because you place a script element in a specific position, does not mean whatever elements it might create, will also be appended in that very same position. We would need to see what these scripts actually do, before anyone can say any more about this.

Comment: Basically it's network diagraming tool called NextUI: https://github.com/NeXt-UI/next

Comment: Contents of you're `base.html` is relevant here.  From what you've provided it looks like those `<link>` tags (and the `next.js` script tag) are not inside the `<head>` element which they should be - as per the [quickstart](https://github.com/NeXt-UI/next#quick-start).